# PHP: How to change "if"-condition order dynamically

Tags: php, dynamic, if-statement

The situation is like this: there is a continuous loop, that updates some values. Then the script checks certain conditions. The (simplified) code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
// etc
while(1==1)
{
    $a = getFromDatabase('a'); // function to get value of A
    $b = getFromDatabase('b'); // function to get value of B
    $c = getFromDatabase('c'); // function to get value of C
    $d = getFromDatabase('d'); // function to get value of D

    if($a >= 12 && time() <= $b && ($d === false || $d <= time()))
    {
         include 'pages/'.$a.'.php';
    }
    if($b <= 3 && time() >= $d && ($c === false || $c <= time()))
    {
         include 'pages/'.$b.'.php';
    }
}
```

My question is: how can I change the order of these IF-statements dynamically?

Like

```
$order = array('b','a'); // first b then a
```

Important: the if conditions are really dynamic. So there is no real pattern (the example above is simplified, so not the full conditions)

Comment: What? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Why are doing this?  Can you give more information as to what you are doing?  Your code, as it stands currently, is scary.

Comment: i think you just need mo more IFs if you try to achieve what you want :D

Comment: It is a "robot" that check times in a database, if the time is passed it will execute certain commands.

Comment: that isn't really helpful.  Can you give more insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in functions, then just store the name of the functions and go through each in turn.

```
function func1($a, $b, $c, $d)
{
  if (...)
  {
    return $a
  }
  return false;
}

function func2($a, $b, $c, $d)
 ...

$funcs = Array('func1', 'func2');

 ...

foreach($funcs as $func)
{
  if ($page = $func($a, $b, $c, $d))
  {
    include "pages/$page.php"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you want, but you can put `if` in functions:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
function a($a,$b,$c,$d){
        if($a >= 12 && time() <= $b && ($d === false || $d <= time()))
        {
             include 'pages/'.$a.'.php';
        }
}
function b($a,$b,$c,$d){
        if($b <= 3 && time() >= $d && ($c === false || $c <= time()))
        {
             include 'pages/'.$b.'.php';
        }
}

// etc
while(1==1)
{
    $a = getFromDatabase('a'); // function to get value of A
    $b = getFromDatabase('b'); // function to get value of B
    $c = getFromDatabase('c'); // function to get value of C
    $d = getFromDatabase('d'); // function to get value of D
    $order = array('b','a'); // first b then a
    foreach( $order as $fun)
        call_user_func_array($fun, array($a,$b,$c,$d))
}
```